# How welcome page works when using JDBC Realm?

Tags: java, authentication, jdbc, web.xml, container-managed

When setting up JDBC Realm we specify the form-login-page which loads at first for authentication. If it occurs first, how the welcome file specified in web.xml loads? Will JDBC Realm redirect to welcome file when login is success?

Comment: It doesn't occur first. It occurs when you navigate to a URL that needs authentication. That could be the welcome file but more commonly it isn't.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand how it works

Answer (score 0):

It will go to whatever page you were trying to access that triggered the authentication.

This is not peculiar to the welcome page or to JDBCRealm.

Comment: It would be great if you can explain how this whole thing works shortly. I am confused about the workflow of it

Comment: It works by remembering what you were trying to do when you hit the authentication requirement, and then taking you there once you authenticate successfully.

Comment: Thank you for simple and clean explanation :)